# What is the best way to detect memory leaks in a PyQt application?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pyqt

I am developing a PyQt desktop application, on Linux, to be used in an industrial setting. It is basically a sensor data logger which displays real time graph and saves the data into a database. As it must run continuously 5 x 24 hours per week, I need to make sure there is no memory leak for it to run smoothly.

So, what is the best way to detect memory leaks in my application?

Comment: Python has a garbage collector as well as Qt so if you don't write any C++ code yourself I don't think you need that check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Memory Profiling Using tracemalloc

> `tracemalloc` is a package included in the Python standard library.
>
> > It provides detailed, block-level traces of memory allocation, including the full traceback to the line where the memory allocation occurred, and statistics for the overall memory behavior of a program.

`tracemalloc` can be used to locate high-memory-usage areas of code in two ways:

- looking at cumulative statistics on memory use to identify which object allocations are using the most memory, and
- tracing execution frames to identify where those objects are allocated in the code.

A link for the documentation and PEP are below. Both provide excellent instructions on how to detect anomalies in Pythons memory management.

- [Tracemalloc Documentation Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#module-tracemalloc)
- [PEP454](https://peps.python.org/pep-0454/)

Comment: This won't help if the memory leak is in Qt or any other extension library that uses C/C++ (which is an ever-present possibility). To get useful information about the source of the leak, you really need to run the application with debug versions of all the relevant libraries, and then use something like valgrind.

Comment: @ekhumoro that sounds like a better idea then mine, why wouldn't you answer the OPs question?

Comment: It's unclear to me what the OP's real question is, since the title doesn't match the content. Prevention is obviously very different to detection. Also, given the context in which the code is ultimately supposed to run, I'd rather just let it rip in a sandboxed environment first and see what actually happens.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro my apologies for the ambiguity. I have updated the question and hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @andre No, it still isn't really clear at all. If your application is a critical component which you are responsible for maintaining, surely you must already employ a test framework that covers most of the potential issues? If your testing has revealed a possible memory leak, you *might* be able to identify the source using the suggestions given so far, but it's not guaranteed. I doubt whether there's really anything you can do to *guarantee* detection in all possible scenarios - but I'm not an expert in this area, so I could be wrong.